# how to stop timer after a given millisecond in c

Tags: c++, c, timer, milliseconds

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>   
int main (void)
{
double diff = 0.0;
time_t start;
time_t stop;
time(&start);
print("Enter millisecond to stop");
```

so what is code should add to stop timer after given interval of timer

Comment: `time` returns in seconds use `gettimeofday`. u cannot achieve millisecond precision with `time`. man 2 time

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense without specifying a given system. If you are programming on a standard desktop OS (Windows, Linux, Mac etc) then there is no such thing as millisecond accuracy, because you need a RTOS for that. And even if the intended target is a RTOS, you can probably not use `time`, because it is intended to give calendar time, rather than high resolution timing.

Comment: I'd put `time(&start);` **after** the user entered the interval. And: `time()` returns seconds. So trying to measure milliseconds with it does not make sense.

Comment: You might like to look around on SO, there are dozens of questions like yours.

Comment: Also decide: C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int seconds;
scanf ("%d",&seconds);
stop = 0;
while (stop < start + seconds)
    time(&stop);
```

Comment: Your loop is a busy loop. It will consume one of your CPU cores at 100%. Try using a sleep (nanosleep probably) instead to "pause" your process.

Comment: @jackrabbit Sleep functions cannot be used for accurate millisecond timing purposes, [read this](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm#Sleep).

Comment: You're pointing me at a page from 10 years ago on the use of sleeping for thread synchronisation being defective? Threads are nowhere to be seen in the above code. I'm just saying that, for waiting a significant amount of time, you probably don't want to write a busy-loop.